# the question here

Tags: word-usage

Does "here" refer back to "the publishing house"?

> Sam Harris liked
> Bari Weiss tweeted hours ago:
> Why is the publishing house even entertaining these complaints? That’s **the question here** and in so many other institutions:

> [Source](https://twitter.com/bariweiss/status/1331416908797796356)

Comment: I think 'here' means the article attached to the tweet that you are currently looking at.

Comment: The problem in understanding is that the tweeter also said "in so many other institutions" - it implies that "(in this institution and) in so many other institutions" - A publishing house is an instituion (an established official organization).